# Como enviar campos de um formulário por e-mail no formato de uma tabela?

Tags: c#, envio-de-email, stringbuilder

Minha aplicação pega alguns dados que o usuário preenche nos campos de TextBox (txtEmpresa, txtContato, etc...) e os envia para um e-mail pré-configurado. Consigo enviar os dados por meio do smtp, mas estão sendo enviados sem formatação. Como formatar os dados para que sejam enviados no formato de uma tabela, como por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Use HTML.

Na hora de enviar o e-mail, passe o HTML gerado como texto do email e ative a opção de corpo da mensagem como HTML. Não sei o que você usa pra enviar e-mail, então fica difícil melhorar, se você der mais detalhes, ajudo mais. Posso adiantar que usando o `SmtpClient` padrão do .NET é só fazer `mensagem.IsBodyHtml = true`.

Escrever o código HTML no próprio código pode ficar ruim e desorganizado, você pode usar templates pra isso. Se quiser optar pela simplicidade, você pode criar *um arquivo HTML, colocar tokens* no lugar dos dados (ex.: `##nome_empresa##`) e substituir antes de fazer o envio. É possível usar o [PostalMvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Postal.Mvc5/) e várias outras bibliotecas.

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>Empresa</th>
            <!-- seguir criando os TH's -->
        <tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td>Nome da empresa</td>
            <!-- seguir criando os TD's -->
        <tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu faço assim:

Criação do HTML:

Eu não gosto de escrever HTML no código C#. Fica ruim de ler e dar manutenção na minha opinião, principalmente quando tem muitos atributos e CSS e tem que ficar dando escape nas strings. Eu crio um arquivo Resource.resx (Add New Item, Resource File). Então nele eu crio uma string que é template para o HTML.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois eu faço a substituição:

```
string strMensagem = Resource.htmlEmail;
strMensagem = strMensagem.Replace("{nome}", txtNome.Text);
strMensagem = strMensagem.Replace("{contato}", txtTelefone.Text);
```

Envio - há varias formas de enviar como por APIs pagas ou por SMTP-Client

```
var email = new MailMessage();
var strSenha = "aaaaa";
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
{
   smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("foo@gmail.com", strSenha);
   smtp.EnableSsl = true;
   email.To.Add(strDestinatario);
   email.IsBodyHtml = true;
   email.Subject = strAssunto;
   email.Body = strMensagem;
   smtp.Send(email);
}
```

Como eu disse essa é a forma que gosto de fazer, mas você poderia criar o HTML direto numa string. Com a nova interpolação de string do C# 6.0 isso fica um pouco mais fácil.

```
string html = "<table>" +
              " <thead>" + 
              "  <tr>" +
              "   <th>Empresa</th>" +
              "   <th>Contato</th>" +
              "  </tr>" +
              " </thead>" +
              " <tbody>" +
              "  <tr>" +
             $"   <td>{txtNome.Text}</td>" +
             $"   <td>{txtTelefone.Text}</td>" +
              "  </tr>" +
              " </tbody>" +
              "</table>";
```